# How to initialize firebase dynamically in angular 7 after getting the configuration via http call

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

i'm trying to initialize the firebase dynamically after getting the config file via http call using @angular/fire. but all the documents and search is pointing me to initialize it in app.module.ts like below.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

is it possible to call the initializeApp in any service like below

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseSyncService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    initializeFirebase() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/get-config?db=12345';
        this.httpClient.get<any>(url).subscribe(response => {
            AngularFireModule.initializeApp(response.config);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you've got an API that returns the configuration when you can just hardcode it in your `environment.ts` file?

Comment: @Edric i have multiple app running on a single project which is a platform (to enhance code re usability). hence i want each app to have their own firebase db, and for security purpose we are making a call to local db and fetching the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a simple hack after many hair pulling.

my environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebase: getConfig()
};

function getConfig() {
    let config;
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/index/get-config', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
        request.send(null);

        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            config = request.responseText;
        }

        return JSON.parse(config);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('environment:getConfig: unable to get api key : ', e);
    }

    return config;
}
```

My Lazy loaded module import:

```
@NgModule({
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
})
```

Next in service or any component, inject and use as normal

```
 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
```

Hope this helps for anyone in the future.

Comment: You should use the `HttpClient` API from `@angular/common/http` instead of the browser `XMLHttpRequest` API: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @Edric how could you inject `HttpClient` into `environmet.ts` file?

Comment: Also message from Chrome `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience`

Comment: Were you able to build the project in production mode (ng build --prod) with this approach ?

Comment: @Faouzi No, it didn't work, sorry will modify the answer.

Comment: @AnuroopS, I found a workaround which works in production mode , I will post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AngularFire has any configuration of its own, so you can just use the regular JavaScrip initialization code shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup (select the "from the CDN" tab):

```
// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

You'll need to make sure that the `DEFAULT` app gets initialized before any other Firebase services are used.

Comment: Found a small hack, it works. Don't know if this is the right way though. please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

For those who has have **problems building the project in production mode (ng build --prod)**, you need to initialize firebase in a provider instead of doing it directly in the imports array.

`app.module` (or the module where you initialize firebase)

```
 @NgModule({
     ...
 imports: [
   ...
   AngularFireModule, // do NOT initialize firebase here
   ...
 ],
 providers:[
  {
   provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, 
   useValue: environment.firebase  //initialize firebase from env here
  } 
 ]
  ...
})
```

environment.ts  (keep the same code as the accepter answer)

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebase: getConfig()
};

function getConfig() {
    let config;
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/index/get-config', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
        request.send(null);

        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            config = request.responseText;
        }

        return JSON.parse(config);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('environment:getConfig: unable to get api key : ', e);
    }

    return config;
}
```