# Angularfire load firebase config asynchronoulsy

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous, continuous-integration, angularfire

I want to load the firebaseConfig asynchronously because I want to seperate config from artifact, to be able to have a clean CI/CD pipeline (build once, run on any environment, get config from server).

But to use firebase I need to call provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)) inside of the imports of my AppModule. How can I do this if firebaseConfig must be loaded asynchronously?

What I would like to do:

```js
let config: { firebase: any };

function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => httpClient.get('https://myserver.com/api/config').pipe(c => config = c)
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => {
      return initializeApp(config.firebase); 
      // THIS DOES NOT WORK, because the APP_INITIALIZER is async! How can we also make this import async?!?
    })],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient],
    multi: true,
  }],
})
```

Comment: Hi, tried to find any docs or information about your issue. Honestly looks like there is no clean way to do this but there is a similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469571/angular-load-external-configuration-before-appmodule-loads

Take a look at all the answers, accepted one has some issues as they tell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69614605/17427052 what about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a satisfying solution :D

In main.ts, I can load the config from the server and write it to e.g. my environment file:

```js
(async () => {
  environment.appConfig = await fetch(environment.apiUrl + 'environment/frontend-config/myApp').then((res) => res.json());
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
})();
```

And then I dont even need an app initializer, I can just use the environment file as I usually would:

```js
provideFirebaseApp(() => {
  return initializeApp(environment.appConfig.firebase); 
})],
```

To make it even nicer I wrapped it all in a configService that is available in all my apps.